# Any risks changing session save type

Tags: session

Does changing the session save type from database to file have any affect to store functioning when changing it in live site? I'm presuming at least current sessions are cut off. Working with Magento 1.7.0.2. Any other risks that I should consider / tackle?

Answer (score 1):

except cutting off all existing sessions, there should be no other side effects.

Maybe ensure that the web server has write permissions on the var/ dir. But, it should have, since otherwise you most likely would have other problems too.